# Desgin time not matching runtime, label spacing out

Tags: delphi, browser, delphi-11-alexandria, tms, tms-web-core

I have run into issues with design time not matching up with runtime.
This is a new project, with just a panel and 7 labels. I am using Edge browser, I have tried to correct it with clearing cache but issue still persists, I have tried to use chrome, issue still persists, and i have also made a brand-new application and the issue still persists. I have also disabled "Debugging inside of ide" under the TMS Web options.
What could be causing this and how do I fix it?
I am using TMS WEB Core v2.3.1.0
Thank You

[image: Design Time]
DFM code:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Width = 1364
  Height = 811
  object WebPanel1: TWebPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 1364
    Height = 85
    Align = alTop
    ShowCaption = False
    object WebLabel1: TWebLabel
      Left = 1315
      Top = 0
      Width = 49
      Height = 85
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 0
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Log in'
      HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      Layout = tlCenter
      WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
    object WebLabel2: TWebLabel
      Left = 1254
      Top = 0
      Width = 61
      Height = 85
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 0
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Contact'
      HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      Layout = tlCenter
      WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
    object WebLabel3: TWebLabel
      Left = 1218
      Top = 0
      Width = 36
      Height = 85
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 0
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Blog'
      HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      Layout = tlCenter
      WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
    object WebLabel4: TWebLabel
      Left = 1124
      Top = 0
      Width = 94
      Height = 85
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 0
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Mobile App'
      HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      Layout = tlCenter
      WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
    object WebLabel5: TWebLabel
      Left = 1061
      Top = 0
      Width = 63
      Height = 85
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 0
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Website'
      HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      Layout = tlCenter
      WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
    object WebLabel6: TWebLabel
      Left = 927
      Top = 0
      Width = 134
      Height = 85
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 0
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Business in a Box'
      HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      Layout = tlCenter
      WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
    object WebLabel7: TWebLabel
      Left = 878
      Top = 0
      Width = 49
      Height = 85
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 0
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Home'
      HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      Layout = tlCenter
      WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
  end
end
```

Runtime:

[image: Runtime]

Comment: You're better off using the form's .html file to create your design.  You can place TWebLabels on your form and use the TWebLabel.ElementID to map to your html design. Much easier than trying to use WebCore in WSIWYG mode.

Comment: I tested this on my side and it's working fine on my side. I don't have any weird spacing issues. What I see in design-time is exactly what I see in run-time.

Comment: What version of TMS Web Core are you running?

Comment: TMS WEB Core
v2.3.1.0

Comment: And you have the `AutoSize` property set to `True` for all of the labels? If yes, then try setting `AutoSize` to `True` via code in run-time and see if it makes a difference. Maybe do the same with `AlignWithMargins` as `False` also. I want to make sure it's not overriding the default values somewhere for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a High DPI issue.

What fixed this for me was going to
"Options>User Interface>Form Designer>High DPI" and then changing the "VCL Designer High DPI Mode *" to "Automatic (Screen PPI)". Mine was set on "Low DPI".

[image: Delphi High DPI Options]

Then I saved and closed my project, completely exited my IDE, reloaded the project, and the issue was sorted.